# ReactJS use content script without ejecting (Chrome Extension)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to use the content script without having to eject from my app. 
Problem is I need to disable the renaming react does to the content script during the building phase.

Is there a clean way to do this without ejecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at rescript : https://github.com/harrysolovay/rescripts/tree/master/packages (maybe it has what you need !)
Or react-app-rewired if you are using react-script 1.x